# Request-reply with Oracle AQ

Tags: oracle-aq

I want to implement the [request-reply](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/RequestReplyJmsExample.html) pattern using Oracle AQ. Basically a "requestor" would:

1. Enqueue a request message.
2. Take the message ID generated for the request message.
3. Dequeue the reply message, specifying in the [dequeue options](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/t_aq.htm#ARPLS71684) the **correlation** property as being the message ID of the original request message.

It turns out that the in the DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE procedure, the msgid OUT parameter which returns the original message ID is a **RAW**, while the correlation property of the dequeue options is a **VARCHAR2(128)**.

What is the correct way to implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I was afraid of simply trying to convert a RAW to a VARCHAR2 (after all, if the return of the API is a RAW, for me, this means that the bytes do not necessarily correspond to a String in a particular charset), it seems that it is just a matter of converting the RAW msgId to VARCHAR2 using TO_CHAR. Curiously, it does not work if you try to use UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR.

I will proceed with this approach, although it does not make me 100% confident.